# Changing page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, navigation

I building a Phonegap application. I have 7-8 pages, and I need to navigate between them using Javascript. I have tried using`window.open` and `window.location` but those don't work.

How do I change the page using Javascript?

Comment: window.location.href and window.open() should both work. Can you post some code?

Comment: Yes, you are right, window.open() works but it open pop up... about window.location.href - not works, here code:
  <body>
  <script src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">alert("index.html");
            window.location.href = "ltr.startPage.html?tagId=-1";
        </script>
 </body>

Comment: use `window.open("ltr.startPage.html?tagId=-1", "_self")` to open a page in the same window

Comment: Thanks, seems that this it works, but maybe better use Phonegap browser,  InAppBrowser: window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

Answer (score 5):

the following code working for me.

**window.location="success.html";**

after login success I am calling above code. It is redirecting to success page in android phonegap.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It switches to a blank page that says `Cannot GET /noConnection.html`. I'm trying to show page is the user has no connection.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. i think it will help you.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onClick="goPage1();">Go to Page1</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function goPage1()
{
   var dirPath = dirname(location.href);
   fullPath = dirPath + "/page1.html";
   window.location=fullPath;
}
function dirname(path)
{
   return path.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '');
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It switches to a blank page that says `Cannot GET /noConnection.html`. I'm trying to show page is the user has no connection. Just like the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

if it's the same hostname you can simply change page with **pathname** :

for exemple if you have files names :

> index.html

> login.html

you can go to *login.html* with :

```js
window.location.pathname = "login.html";
```