# How to change Current URL using JS when a button clicked ( for changing language)

Tags: javascript, url

Suppose my current URL is :
http://arshohag.com/en/home

I want to change it to :
http://arshohag.com/bn/home

how can i do that using JS ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing page using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312158/changing-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add a bit to Lazy Coder's answer...

html:

```
<a href='bn' id='button'>Change Language to BN</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.body.getElementById('button'); // assuming there is a button with the id='button';

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();//to stop link from processing.
   var lang = button.href; // gets language from link
   window.location = 'http://arshohag.com/'+lang+'/home';
}
```

Comment: I m a beginner ... just can't find a way ........ thanks for your idea ...... it helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your JS click event

```
  window.location = 'http://arshohag.com/bn/home'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change it with this line :

```
window.location.pathname = "/bn/home";
```